# How to build a controll panel with cakePHP/MVC frameworks

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm building a simple Virtual Learning Environment(VLE) system for a test project with CakePHP. The project contains the following:

- Courses
- Lessons
- Questions
- Answers

I've made the Controller, Models and Views for the courses and Lessons and I'm able to add lessons to a course and delete them. I've generally been following cakePHPs blog tutorial and changing as I go along.

This however leaves me with a very rigid structure of content and pages and URL's (I understand how to change the URL's to be more user and SEO friendly with Routes). My pages are all /{controler}/{method}

Part of the project is to create a management panel for the courses. On the page you can see lessons, and the students assigned to the course with links to add/edit these.

I can not however work out how to do this combination of several models into an admin style page. I can think of a few ways of dong this involving perhaps cakePHP pages, or routes and bringing one models data into another's controller to get it into the view. However **I am trying to find out the correct way of doing this with cakePHP** or failing that in MVC frameworks in general.

I apologise if this is laid out anywhere obvious but I've looked and have yet of find any answer that coveres my issue is a laid out fashion. Unfortunately I really need this spelling out for me as I'm just overwhelmed with a lot of MVC without anyone to ask and haivng only worked in CMS systems.

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem. Could you explain a little better what you want to do? You say you already have the "see lessons and add/edit students", but what do you mean by "how to do this combination of several models into an admin style page"?

Comment: I think he just means "I have a page that's not really tied to a specific Controller or single set of data - how should I manage it?"

Comment: @Dave Yeah, I put it together after reading your answer and drinking a cup of coffee, thx :)

Comment: Yeah to expand a bit. I have done it all separate, a page for each action, page for index of all the lessons, all the questions, all the courses. I want to be on a admin page for a course, and see all the lessons it has, all the users on that course and link to actions of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a Controller called "DashboardsController" or something like that.

Within it's actions, you can load any model(s) you want, then use it just as you would in the respective Controller:

```
$this->loadModel('Course');
$courses = $this->Course->find('all');
$this->set(compact('courses'));
```

**This is a very common problem/solution**, and I believe I even asked this same question a few years ago on here myself (though I couldn't find it).  You still retain the MVC structure, as it still acts as the Controller - it just accesses methods from varying models.

It's incredibly common to call more than just the model of the controller you're in, so in a case like this, you just load whichever models you want/need.

You can make a `Dashboard.php` model as well and just set

```
$useTable = false;
```

to tell it you don't need a "dashboards" table.

I have one of these "generic" controllers in almost every project I do, and am not really sure of any other/better way to handle it.  This seems the cleanest, easiest, and most logical approach IMO.

Comment: How would this work with linking to other controllers actions. For instance I've made a dashboards controller. And in it a teacher action. In this view there is a link to add student that forwards me to /users/add.

Now the way I've coded /users/add by following the tutorials will return me to users/index once a new user is added. How would I get back to the dashboard after I dive into the actions of other ciontrollers?

Comment: Just change your redirect to go back to dashboard (or to `referer`) instead of the user index.